# Do re-implanted avulsed tooth heal completely?

Tags: dentistry, oral-health, implant, self-healing-repairing

I had a tooth re-implanted by a dentist and it's been two weeks and it is getting harder and stronger. My question is, will the tooth heal completely or do I need to go under a dentistry procedure..?

Comment: More information is needed, such as _age_of_patient_. This information can help us determine if the apex (root) is still open or not, which has a direct effect on the chances that it will revascularise and remain without symptoms. I would not discount the possibility of a root canal in the future if other problems arise. The fact that it became firmer could indicate that the gums and the tooth are reattaching normally.